# Basic pi searcher in C, whats wrong?

Tags: c, pi

So I tried making a basic pi searcher based on the Gregory-Leibniz series. My problem is it returns 3.0000, and I don't have a clue why...

This is the basic program:

```
int i = 1, j = 1;
double pi = 0;

for (i; i < 1000; i++)
{
    if(i % 2 != 0)
    {
        pi = pi + (4 / j);
    }
    else
    {
        pi = pi - (4 / j);
    }


    j = j + 2;
}
```

Comment: What did you discover when you debugged the program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `4/j` is entirely integer math, which means it will round down to an integer before being added. Some options are `4.0 / j` and `(double)4 / j`.

The MSDN has an article on [C floating-point constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9bk1wcy.aspx) that explains the notation you should use to ensure a literal value is treated as a float or a double.

Answer (score 1):

`j` has values 1, 3, 5, 7, etc...

Let me ask you:  What value do you *think* `4/1`, `4/3`, `4/5`, and `4/7` has?
Explain exactly ***why*** you think that.

*(hint: you are likely wrong)*

Answer (score 0):

Your divisions are using integer divisions

```
(4 / j) // returns 0 when j is greater than 4
```

Use `4.0` to do floating point operations instead